# MongoDB aggregate for daily won/lost games, $cond is always false

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a couple of `$match`'s and `$unwind`'s and end up with a collection of documents looking like this:

```json
{
_id:249776348,
StartGameTime:1615789789,
team:0,
winner:0
}
```

So I'm converting the `_id` field to a date (that works fine) and then I'm trying to do a daily won/lost count. The data should be read like this: team is the team the player was on, and winner is the team that won, so `{ team: 0, winner: 0 }` and `{ team: 1, winner: 1 }` indicated the player won.

This is what I got, a `$group` done in MongoDB Compass' UI:

```js
{
  _id: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: {$add: [ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'),  {$multiply: [1000,"$StartGameTime"]  }]}}},
  won: {
    $sum: {
        $cond: [{$or: [{$and: [{$eq: ["team", 1]},{$eq: ["winner", 1]}]},{$and: [{$eq: ["team", 0]},{$eq: ["winner", 0]}]}]}, 1, 0]
    }
  },
  lost: {
    $sum: {
        $cond: [{$or: [{$and: [{$eq: ["team", 1]},{$eq: ["winner", 0]}]},{$and: [{$eq: ["team", 1]},{$eq: ["winner", 0]}]}]}, 1, 0]
    }
  }
}
```

And unfortunately it always gives my `won: 0` and `lost: 0`

I bet it's something obvious, but I just can't spot it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply comparing the `team` and `winner` value? For won case, if `team` == `winner`, then count + 1, else count + 0.
Vise versa for lost, but the condition become `team` != `winner`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            $add: [
              ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
              {
                $multiply: [
                  1000,
                  "$StartGameTime"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      won: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$team",
                "$winner"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      lost: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $ne: [
                "$team",
                "$winner"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0KkzF-7gzmA) for your reference.